# Offsetting symbology in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, symbology, arcgis-online

I have a line feature class that I would like to add to an AGOL map. To get the appropriate symbology, I need to have certain portions of the line to have two colors running parallel to each other. 
In ArcMap, this is easy since you would just offset one of the lines. However there is no offset feature in AGOL. Also when I create the symbology in ArcMap and bring it into AGOL, I am unable to import symbology.
Is there something I should be doing? Or am I just not able to do this AGOL?

Comment: This support article might help you out: http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012452 . Also if you are using the same feature template (symbology and fields) you can copy that feature service in AGOL to publish an empty feature layer with the same symbology and fields.

Comment: That's a bummer. Thanks for the response and suggestion

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @RussRoberts:

> This support article might help you out:
>   [FAQ: Is it possible to import a symbol from ArcMap to ArcGIS Online?](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012452) . Also if you are
>   using the same feature template (symbology and fields) you can copy
>   that feature service in AGOL to publish an empty feature layer with
>   the same symbology and fields.